# How to write regex for Text field accepts string with no special character or it can be a email?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regex. I need a regex pattern  to validate the input text field that can accept string without special character. If "@" is added it should validate for email field. I have tried with following.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\s._-]{3,}(?(?=@)[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}|$
```

Comment: anything here help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Comment: thanks, but the validation depends on @,if @ is there then it should validate for email. The requirement is user can either enter their username or their mail id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your regex with small changes:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\s._-]{3,}(?:@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}|$)
```

Basically it now matches either the part with `@` or end of string.